# Is it able to create an HTTP triggered python function on Azure Function without doing any local coding?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I wonder is it able to create an HTTP triggered python function on Azure Function without doing any local coding? I want to do everything on Azure cloud. My python function codes are in a Github/Azure repos repository, but I do not have all the extra files of an Azure function project (for example, a **init**.py script file that is the HTTP trigger function of the Azure Function App). Is it possible to generate those files from Azure (without generating any Azure Function related files on my local computer)? I noticed that we cannot do in-portal editing for Python function Apps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we can just deploy the python function from local to Azure cloud, but can not deploy it as you expected. And I think it will not be too difficult to us to deploy the python function from local to azure cloud.

Since you have had the main python function code "init.py", you just need to sign in to Azure in you VS code and create python function by following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-01). And then use your init.py code to replace the new python function code. After that, run the command below in "TERMINAL" window to generate the "requirements.txt":

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

**The "requirements.txt" includes all of the modules which imported in your "init.py" and when the function deployed to azure, azure will install these modules by this "requirements.txt". I saw you mentioned you don't have all the extra files of this function project, if these modules are what you care about, the "requirements.txt" will solve your problem.**

Then use this command to deploy it to Azure:

```
func azure functionapp publish hurypyfunapp --build remote
```